# Adding more functions to Backbone Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am attempting to add some functions to backbone so that I can communicate with mongodb. Now I know this won't work client side; however, I do like backbone's functionality for server side model logic as well. I noticed that I would be doing a bunch of repeat work if I kept adding the same functionality for each model so decided to create a "app_model" file to extend backbone when I'm server side. I also don't want to override the standard Backbone functions because they will be useful client side.

So let's take this user class for instance:

```
var Backbone = require('./app_model');

var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name : "users",
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            username: "default",
            role: 2,
            created: new Date(),
            updated: new Date(),
            logged: new Date()
        };
    },
    idAttribute: "username",
    /**
     * A predefined listing of user roles
     */
    userRoles: [
        "admin",  //0
        "author", //1
        "user"    //2
    ],
    initialize: function() {
        if(!!app) {
           this.svrInit();
        }
    }
});

module.exports = User;
```

And I want to append functions onto backbone by using my "app_model.js" file, which looks something like this currently:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
  Deferred = require('Deferred'),
  when = Deferred.when;

Backbone.Model.prototype.svrInit = function() {
    //TODO: perhaps the code below should be made static some how so we don't have a bunch of instances of collection
    var model = this;
    if(!!app.db){
        app.db.collection(this.name,function(err,collection){
            model.collection = collection;
        });
    }
};

Backbone.Model.prototype.svrSave = function() {
    var model = this.toJSON();
    var dfd = new Deferred();
    this.collection.insert(model, {safe:true}, function(err, result){
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    return dfd;
};

Backbone.Model.prototype.svrFind = function(options) {
    var model = this.toJSON();
    var dfd = new Deferred();
    this.collection.find(options, {safe:true}, function(err, result){
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    return dfd;
};

module.exports = Backbone;
```

I ran my tests when I abstracted this out and it seemed to work alright. Is there a better way to do any of this? Any pit falls? I am using the global "app" variable, is that bad? If so what are some ways around it? I do find it ugly that I had to put `this.svrInit()` inside the init function at the model level is there anyway to automatically make that happen after creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've been thinking about this question for a couple days and I the cleanest thing I've come up with is something like this:

```
var MyModel = function( attributes, options ) {
  Backbone.Model.apply( this, arguments );
  this.specialInitializer();
};

MyModel.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;

_.extend( MyModel.prototype, Backbone.Model.prototype, {
  specialInitializer: function() {
    // called after the users 'initialize'
    console.log("MyModel initialized.", this);
  },
  otherNewMethod: function() {
    // this is just like any other instance method,
    // just as if Backbone.Model implemented it
  }
} );
```

So what this does is basically make an entirely new 'kind' of `Backbone.Model`. One which also calls `specialInitializer`. If you look at the [backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) just after the constructor definition for `Backbone.Model` you'll see this is a similar strategy.

- Construct the instance.
- Call an initializer the implementor is supposed to define.
- Extend the prototype with functionality (in their case `Backbone.Events`, in ours, `Backbone.Model`).

Your new initializer can of course call whatever else it needs, etc.

As for your other questions about the static collection stuff and global app variable, I'm afraid I don't follow exactly what is going on there since I don't see a definition for `app` and don't know what you're using the collection for.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3cgz/) that demonstrates this with some extra logging and such.

Comment: Ahh, I see! I've seen some similar concepts floating around, but wasn't sure how it was achieved. 

Part of my question was about Node.JS. I have a server.js file that defines a variable app using expressjs.  It is a global, and accessible through the server side portion of my app. All the examples I have seen do this. I guess I could sort of think of it as "window" or "document"; however, I created a db connection and threw it into the `app` variable as well. Otherwise I'd be creating new DB connections for every model. I guess this makes sense. However, using globals is discouraged...

Comment: `app.db.collection` is the app global variable. db is part of mongodb's NodeJS library. collection refers to a mongodb collection. If you don't know about collections, they are basically like tables. So I am preforming find and insert operations on them.

Comment: Also I like that solution for calling the initialize function! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm familiar with MongoDB and Node, but I must be missing something. Are you using Backbone on the server side? If so I think it's ok to use globals like you are.

Comment: Yea, I am using backbone server side and trying to reuse the same classes client side as well. I think I am going to use requirejs client side and have a different `MyModel` class used there. That way I can keep most of the model logic intact including validations and such. I can even do things like use Deferred from jQuery as opposed to the other library I am currently using server side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a fairly large code-base with 4-5 levels of inheritance in the views.  This is the pattern I'm using:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.Model.extend({
  somefunc: function() {
    //contents
  },

  otherfunc: function(a,b,c) {
    //contents
  },
  //...
});


var User = BaseView.extend({
  // things in user view can now access somefunc and otherfunc
});
```

Here's a quick example in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqZ4u/1/) (note the doSearch function being inherited)

Comment: Yea we recently used this pattern to a point. We noticed 4->5 levels of inheritance got us into a bunch of trouble. We decided the mixin pattern was pretty useful in conjunction with some limited amount of inheritence. We use: https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/Backbone.Advice